# Usar CASE em uma clausula WHERE

Tags: sql-server, where, case

Preciso usar uma condição dentro de um parametro de filtro em um relatório. Basicamente a regra é determinada por um campo vachar que o valor dele é 'T' ou 'P'. Tentei uma solução como abaixo mas não deu muito certo.

A regra é, se o campo for 'T' filtro pelo campo Dt_Cad, se o valor for 'P' filtro pelo campo Dt_emissao. Alguém sabe se isso é possível?

Abaixo minha tentativa de solução

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos

```
WHERE   (CASE 
        WHEN NotFis.Tp_Nota='P' then
             NotFis.DT_Emissao between '2018-01-01'   and GETDATE()  
        ELSE NotFis.dt_CAD     between '2018-01-01'   and GETDATE()  
        END)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uma solução alternativa que não envolve o `CASE WHEN` é testar Tp_Nota no `WHERE`, assim:

```
WHERE ( 
        (NotFis.Tp_Nota='P' AND (NotFis.DT_Emissao between '2018-01-01' AND GETDATE()))
        OR
        (NotFis.Tp_Nota='T' AND (NotFis.dt_CAD between '2018-01-01' AND GETDATE()))
       )
```

O `CASE WHEN` deve fazer parte da expressão lógica e não "ser a expressão" lógica. 
Funcionaria bem com algo assim:

```
WHERE NotFis.DT_Emissao BETWEEN  '2018-01-01' AND 
       (CASE  WHEN NotFis.Tp_Nota='P' THEN GETDATE()
              ELSE NotFis.dt_CAD    GETDATE()-30
        END)
```

Nesse exemplo acima, ele "faz parte" da expressão (o valor final do BETWEEN).

Comment: Olá Ricardo. Excelente sua primeira solução. Eu estava tentando pensar em algo assim, mas não conseguia. Deu certíssimo. Obrigado também pela explicação

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui solucionar essa mesma situação da seguinte forma:

```
IF @CAMPO = T
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM DADOS WHERE DT_CAD BETWEEN '@DT_INI' AND '@DT_FIM'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM DADOS WHERE DT_EMISSAO BETWEEN '@DT_INI' AND '@DT_FIM' 
END
```

Desta forma o código fica um pouco grande por ter de repeti-lo, mas funcionou.